# Is it possible to have a view's height react to the size of another view dynamically?

Tags: android, xml

I have a `TextView` that has a height of `wrap_content`.On the top and the bottom is a `TextView` line. I was wondering if there is anyway to have the lines resize based on the height determined by the text wrap. See Image below.

Note:  The background of the `TextView` is transparent. so I cannot just draw the line through and use a `FrameLayout`.

[image]

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_connection_line"
    android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/margin_connection_line"
        >

    <View
        android:id="@+id/top_vertical_line"
        android:layout_above="@+id/connection_text"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/font_white"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/connection_text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:padding="@dimen/margin_larger"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="@color/font_white"
        android:background="@drawable/connection_white_border"
        android:text="@string/sample_text"
        />

    <View
        android:id="@+id/bottom_vertical_line"
        android:layout_below="@+id/connection_text"
        android:layout_width="1dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@color/font_white"
        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't really understand if the two lines are `TextViews` or just `Views`.

Anyway you should use a simple `RelativeLayout`. This is to have two lines with 10dp width.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<View
    android:layout_width="10dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />
```